# PHP/Jquery:refresh the captcha on click with jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I use a captcha in my login form and I want to refresh the captcha when I click the captcha itself!but it doesn't work!
my html code:

```
<cite class="fr">
    <img id="captcha_img" src="securimage/securimage_show.php" alt="点击图片刷新验证码"  />
</cite>
```

my jquery code:

```
$('#captcha_img').click(function(){
    //alert("hh");
    $('#captcha_img').attr("src","securimage/securimage_show.php"); 
});
```

I also search some docs about this question and try some other ways,but it still doesn't work,can someone give me some ideas?

Comment: does that alert show when clicked?(if uncommented?)

Comment: yes,It can alert “hh”

Comment: can you post securimage/securimage_show.php code?

Comment: i use a captcha that download from the internet,its link:http://www.phpcaptcha.org/

Comment: Your code is alright. It should work. Test here: http://jsfiddle.net/5Y9mG/1/

Comment: I also think it should work exactly,but it doesn't!

Comment: check this link : http://jsfiddle.net/5Y9mG/1/ You should see that there is no error in your script.

Comment: yeah,there is no error,but it can not refresh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both methods below should work ( uncomment one by one and try it ):

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    $('#captcha_img').on( 'click', function() {
        // $(this).attr( "src","securimage/securimage_show.php?"+Math.random() ); 
        // $(this).attr( "src","securimage/securimage_show.php?"+new Date().getTime() );
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Browser is probably caching image. Try this:

```
$('#captcha_img').click(function() {
    var imageUrl = 'securimage/securimage_show.php?' + new Date().getTime();
    $(this).attr('src', imageUrl); 
});
```

Comment: yeah,when I click the image,it can refresh,but it doesn't display the image,instead it displays the "alt" attr of the <img>

Comment: I am so sorry,this can also work exactle,but I lost the "?" at the end of ".php"

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#captcha_img').click(function(){
    //alert("hh");
    $('#captcha_img').attr("src","securimage/securimage_show.php"); 
     return false;
});
```

Or use `e.preventDefault()` like

```
$('#captcha_img').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#captcha_img').attr("src","securimage/securimage_show.php"); 
     //return false;
});
```

tell me if that works. In this case, return false will work just fine because the event doesn't need to be propagated.

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xF7mJ/1/)

```
$(function () {
    $('#foo').click(swapImages);
    var secondImg = 'http://digital-photography-school.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Acorn256.png';
    function swapImages() {
        var img = $("<img id='foo' src='" + secondImg + "' />");
        $(this).replaceWith(img);
        $(img).click(swapImages);
    }
});
```